# PHP preg_replace - using [ ] generates warnings

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Can someone give me a hand with the following

```
$file = preg_replace("/([^\\])([\\])([^\\rnt])/", "$1$2$2$3", $file);
```

When i  run this i get the following warning: "Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ]"

I want to replace in a string all single \ with double \ if there is no r n or t after it. so \r \n \t should remain as they are. \ also should remain as it is but xx\2 should become xx\2

string example: "lorem ips\um do\\lor s\it amet \r \n 34\3" should become
"lorem ips\\um do\\lor s\\it amet \r \n 34\\3"

Thank in advanced

Comment: Backslashes need to be escaped twice "\\\\", once for PHP strings, once more for the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Change double quotes to single quotes:

```
$file = preg_replace('/([^\\])([\\])([^\\rnt])/', "$1$2$2$3", $file);
```